# Gradle Version 2.10 Required Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Google Sign In Integration by Referring to Following link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add_the_google_services_plugin.

I have the configuration JSON file moved to my project. When i try to compile Class path and Plugin from the above link  in my Gradle, I get a warning saying following :

> Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If
>   using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\Nir
>   Patel\D
>   drive\agile_projects_nirpatel\CountDownTimer\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.10-all.zip

Here is my Project Level build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my App Level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.countdowntimer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

I found the wrapper file mentioned in the Warning and changed the distributionUrl to gradle-201.-all.zip. 
Still does not work.

What am I doing wrong Here?

Answer (score 0):

First of go to your project folder > Gradle > wrapper there you will find these two files. [image]

Then Open this gradle-wrapper file and change the 2.8 version with 2.10.
This should work.[image]

Comment: Just downloaded the latest gradle and the changed the path from settings.
still thanks for the answers...!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in android-studio.
2. Change the distribution url to

   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
3. Rebuild your project.

Refer the attached screenshot.

[image: gradle-wrapper version]

Comment: I had already tried these which did not work for me..!!
Althought I sovled this my self by downloading  latest Gradle from following : http://gradle.org/gradle-download/
then just needed to change the path from settings and done..!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Go to Settings > Builds ,Execution , Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and set  **Use default gradle wrapper**

[image]

- Edit the `Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` file and set the field `distributionUrl`  with:

  `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
- Change the gradle plugin with the latest version

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'`